# Best index type for a numeric range in MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing

What storage type (BTREE, RTREE, HASH) is the best (and **why**) for "from" and "to" to get the fastest result from queries like this:

```
SELECT `title`, `from`, `to` FROM `table_name`
WHERE @year >= `from` AND @year <= `to`
```

@year is the parameter to be replaced with a number

and

all numbers (@year, from, to) are float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE and covering index will using BTREE will be best for this type of query.

```
ALTER TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY ix1(from, to, title);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE KEY ix1(from, to, title) USING BTREE;
```

For covering index you add columns used in where clauses first then columns used in group by the columns used in order by and then columns used in select.

`HASH index` is best for `EQUAL` search and `BTREE index` is best for `range search`.

Comment: actually `title` is not important here, the result of query can be anything but it must be the rows between `from` and `to`

Comment: ...and why BTREE is faster than HASH in this case?

Comment: HASH index is best for EQUAL search and BTREE index is best for range search

Comment: HASH is not "best" for equal search, it's limited to equal search ..